# Convert ambiguous unicode characters into 'canonical' characters

Tags: python, unicode

I'm working on a function that accepts a unicode string (Python 2) and returns the same string with some ambiguous characters replaced with a 'canonical' version.  To give you an idea of what I mean by that here are some examples:

'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0) is converted into 'SPACE' (U+0020)
'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019) is converted into 'APOSTROPHE' (U+0027)

I don't need all unicode characters converted into ASCII, just anything that looks very similar to another character.  The intention is to simplify the converted text so that it can be more easily analyzed.  If there are no (or at least fewer) opportunities for ambiguous characters to show up.

My current implementation simply uses `string.replace()` to execute the replacements noted above,  but I know there are other characters that should be replaced with a space, and other apostrophe-like characters that should be normalized.  Other classes of characters to be normalized are things like double quotes and hyphens.  So I'd like to avoid manually specifying every character replacement, if that's possible.

Comment: This is a very hard, even impossible task considering there are 128,237 current unicode characters and a number of them look similar or even identical. It all depends on what you call "similar" related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph

Comment: This question is off-topic as a library request.  That said, there are quite a few questions on the [unidecode](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=unidecode) library, which might be of interest..

Comment: Why is a library request considered 'off-topic?'

Comment: [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) may be useful.  However, it is aimed at converting Unicode to ASCII, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @MikeHoyle: please visit the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) -- there are a handful of site policies which sometimes trip up new users.

Comment: @DSM Ah, I see, thanks.  I'll try to re-word the question to be more problem-oriented.

Comment: This is a really difficult problem. Mainly because you'd have to spend a lot of time defining what's an "equivalent" character. For some, an em dash conveys a significantly different meaning from a hyphen, while others wouldn't care. And then what about an en dash vs a hyphen? Unicode's thousands of characters are full of cases like this, many of which are hidden in languages you don't know.